# in Emacs, how to turn off abbrevs in css-mode?

Tags: css, emacs

How do I turn off abbrev-mode in css-mode? I have this code in my .emacs but it doesn't work.

```
(add-hook 'css-mode-hook (lambda () (abbrev-mode 0)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From manual:

```
 The mode command should accept one optional argument.  If called
 interactively with no prefix argument, it should toggle the mode
 (i.e., enable if it is disabled, and disable if it is enabled).  If
 called interactively with a prefix argument, it should enable the
 mode if the argument is positive and disable it otherwise.
```

So:

```
(add-hook 'css-mode-hook (lambda () (abbrev-mode -1)))
```

Also quoting from **elisp** `info`:

```
 Disabling a minor mode in a mode hook is a little uglier:

      (add-hook 'text-mode-hook (lambda () (foo-mode -1)))

 However, this is not very commonly done.
```